# I cannot type a lower-case Q-Windows 7 Home Edition

Tags: keyboard

I can type an uppercase Q but I cannot type the lowercase Q?
I have tried restarting, checking settings but lower case Q does not work on any program.

Comment: can you attach a usb keyboard and test that? What's your OS? if it's windows, try booting into safe mode.